# Как реализовать ожидание выполнения всех операций в блоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, asp.net-mvc

```
    public void Add(NewsItemViewModel newsModel, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage, int userId)
    {
        id++;
        allNews.Add(new NewsItem()
        {
            Id = id,
            UserId = userId,
            Title = newsModel.Title,
            Content = newsModel.Content,
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            SourceImage = PictureManager.Upload(uploadedImage, id)
        });
    }
```

Есть такой блок кода. Проблема в том, что при выполнении, переменная id может измениться другим юзером (метод другого юзера ещё до выполнения части `PictureManager.Upload(...)`изменяет ID) и picturemanager.upload примет в качестве параметра не правильный id. Мне нужно как-то поместить этот метод в поток таким образом, чтобы его никто не смог вызвать, пока он не выполниться для того, кто запустил его первым.

Comment: что такое `id`?

Comment: @Igor static int

Answer (score 2):

А почему не так?

```
public void Add(NewsItemViewModel newsModel, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage, int userId)
{
    id++;
    var localId = id;
    allNews.Add(new NewsItem()
    {
        Id = localId,
        UserId = userId,
        Title = newsModel.Title,
        Content = newsModel.Content,
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        SourceImage = PictureManager.Upload(uploadedImage, localId)
    });
}
```

---

Если у вас на деле возможен одновременный вызов функции из различных потоков, а `id` — разделяемая переменная, то следует помнить, что доступ ко **всем**  разделяемым переменным из разных потоков **обязан** быть синхронизирован.

В вашем случае необходимо увеличивать `id` и запоминать его значение под блокировкой. Ваш код будет при этом примерно таким:

```
public void Add(NewsItemViewModel newsModel, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage, int userId)
{
    int localId;
    lock (synchronizer)
    {
        id++;
        localId = id;
    }
    allNews.Add(new NewsItem()
    {
        Id = localId,
        UserId = userId,
        Title = newsModel.Title,
        Content = newsModel.Content,
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        SourceImage = PictureManager.Upload(uploadedImage, localId)
    });
}
```

Если ваши другие объекты тоже являются разделяемыми между потоками (`allNews`?), доступ к ним должен также быть синхронизирован.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72877/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).